# Duplicate column name Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, artisan-migrate

I'm creating migration in **Laravel** and when I run command `php artisan migrate` the command give me the following error

> Duplicate column name 'user_id' ('id' int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, 'user_id' int unsigned not null, 'user_id' int not null, 'order_id_' int unsigned not null, 'order_id' int not null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci)

**This is my migration:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUserOrrderTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
         Schema::create('user_orrder', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->increments('id');

            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

            $table->integer('order_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('user_orrder');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be as:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

instead of `$table->integer('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');`

Read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#foreign-key-constraints).